# Google App Engine: Is it possible to receive a file and email it without saving in Bolbstore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, sendmail, email-attachments

> My application’s client end sends a file to servlet, I want to get
>   this file and send it as an email attachment without saving it.
>
> Please help me how can I do so in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this method:  Write the file to GCS (Google Cloud Storage) with a short Lifecycle, so it deletes itself after a short time:  [GCS Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <LifecycleConfiguration>
        <Rule>
            <Action>
                <Delete/>
            </Action>
            <Condition>
                <Age>1</Age>
            </Condition>
        </Rule>
    </LifecycleConfiguration>
```

Comment: Is there any example to achieve this??

Answer (score 1):

Get your file, and do:

```
String fileName;
byte[] fileContent;

MailService service = MailServiceFactory.getMailService();  
MailService.Message msg = new MailService.Message(); 

// msg.setSender(sender); 
// msg.setReplyTo(replyTo);
// msg.setTo(recepients); 
// msg.setSubject(subject);
// msg.setHtmlBody(message);

ArrayList<Attachment> attachments = new ArrayList<Attachment>();
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(fileName, fileContent);
attachments.add(attachment);

msg.setAttachments(attachments);
service.send(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) you can get a file from a web client upload without saving it.  Send the file as an attachment with [Multi-Part Messages](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail#Multi_Part_Messages) from a byte[] array.